# The eigenvalue/singular values of (large) square random matrices

Tags: random-matrices, eigenvalues, singular-values

$M$ is an iid random matrix with $M_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{g^2}N)$ except that the diagonal entries are $-1$.

I am to compute, *in the limit $N\to\infty$*,

1. the eigenvalue/singular value spectrum/distribution. I.e. we order the eigenvalues according to their relevant values such that $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \dots \ge \lambda_N$, and then we hope to know the mean of each $\lambda_i$) of a random matrix $M$:
   $$\bar \lambda_1, \bar\lambda_2, \dots, \bar \lambda_N$$
2. the mean ($\ln$) thereof:
   $$\langle \ln \lambda \rangle = \frac{\ln\lambda_1 + \ln\lambda_2 + \dots + \ln\lambda_N}N.$$

It seems we can calculate $\langle \ln \lambda \rangle$ using $\det(M)$. Then how can we compute the determinant (also a statistics) of such a random matrix?

We possibly need to use the Wigner semicircular law.
 Possible methods in random matrices or more general probability include

> reductions, the Fourier method, the moment method, the Lindeberg swapping trick, individual  swapping, Stein's method, Predecessor comparison.

$\\\\$

I hope to know any **books or papers** about solving the above (or other) statistics of this (or **simpler** similar) random matrix, or of other 'symmetric' (w.r.t. probability distribution of each entry) matrices, or of other kinds of (large) square random matrices. **The literature of random matrices is vast so I hope to narrow down the scope of my research.** I can read them to find clues. Exact solutions are welcome but not necessarily expected right now.

---

(*This section is unnecessary for answering the question:*) An example of calculation is given as (note that $\mu_i$ below is actually eigenvalues denoted as $\lambda_i$ above. I hope to know what is more general than the example):

> [image: a]

---

This seems to be a seminal paper in the topic:
https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.60.1895

A closely related post: [Spectrum of large random asymmetric matrices with correlation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352559/spectrum-of-large-random-asymmetric-matrices-with-correlation)

Comment: When we know the probability distribution of $\lambda$ or $\lambda_i$, the other relational statistics seems to simply follow from the standard probability calculation, e.g. $\det(M)=\int (\prod_i \lambda_i) \mu(\lambda_i, \dots, \lambda_N)$, where $\mu$ is the probability measure/density, though the details are still unclear.

Answer (score 2):

If I slightly modify your prescription, taking i.i.d. Gaussians (mean zero, variance $g^2/N$) for all matrix elements, including the diagonal elements, then your matrix is a member of the (real) Ginibre ensemble; for large $N$ this modification only subtracts 1 from each eigenvalue.

The density of the eigenvalues in the Ginibre ensemble is given by *Girko's circular law*, and the density of the singular values is given by the *Marchenko-Pastur quarter circular law*, see for example [Around the circular law](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.3343). These densities refer to the bulk of the spectrum, in addition there are of order $\sqrt N$ real eigenvalues, distributed uniformly in the interval $(-1,1)$. This line of real eigenvalues is clearly visible in the numerical data shown below (for $N=100$); notice that the line is surrounded by a narrow depletion region, since the complex eigenvalues are repelled from the real axis. See the plot below.

[image]

<sub>Eigenvalues in the complex plane of 200 real matrices of size 100 × 100 in the Ginibre ensemble, from https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2924</sub>

Comment: 1. Why 'for large  this modification only subtracts 1 from each eigenvalue'? You mean eigenvalues of $\Lambda$ are those of the Ginibre ensemble minus $1$?// 2. Is it true that for the complex Ginibre ensemble, the eigenvalues is homogeneously distributed within a disk $O_d$ of the complex plane (plot in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law + Sommers's paper), and therefore for the real Ginibre ensemble, the probability density of eigenvalues will be projection of $O_d$ onto the real line, and become (actually twice, but the constant will not alter the prob distribution) semi-circular?

Comment: 1) the difference between your matrix and the Ginibre matrix is the unit matrix plus a random Gaussian of variance $1/N$ on each diagonal element; the unit matrix simply subtracts 1 from each eigenvalue and the Gaussians become irrelevant for large $N$; 2) no, the real Ginibre ensemble still has complex eigenvalues, because the matrix is not symmetric; the eigenvalue density consists of the same unit disc as in the complex Ginibre ensemble, with the addition of $\sqrt N$ eigenvalues pinned to the real axis (surrounded by a narrow depletion strip)

Comment: 1. I see, $\lambda_M v = M v  = (G-I) v = G v-I v = \lambda_G v- v = (\lambda_G -1) v$, where $G$ is the real Ginibre ensemble. A minor difference is that $M$ has -1 in diagonal, while $G-I$ has gaussians$-1$. This might cause further complexity when $g$ is large but for small $g$ the approximation seems good enough. For very large $g$ perhaps $M$ would behave like $G$, while for $g$ near 1  $M$'s behavior might be unpredictable.

Comment: Why '...still has complex eigenvalues, because the matrix is not symmetric'?

Comment: a real matrix will have real eigenvalues if $M_{ij}=M_{ji}$; in your case that symmetry does not apply; its eigenvalues may be complex, and in fact what happens is that of order $\sqrt N$ of its eigenvalues are real, the remaining having a nonzero imaginary part.

Comment: It seems that because we have random entries here so probabilistically the real/complex eigenvalues will each take a certain proportion. // Or we can say that the imaginary part $b$ has a prob distribution such that $P(b=0)=\frac {\sqrt N}N=\frac 1{\sqrt N}$, something looking like statistical mechanics.

Comment: no, it is more subtle than this: with just random entries you would not expect to have any eigenvalue with an imaginary part _exactly_ equal to zero; which is what happens here, because of the symmetry relation that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then also its complex conjugate must be an eigenvalue; so imagine starting with a symmetric matrix and perturbing it so that it becomes asymmetric; any eigenvalue on the real axis cannot move into the complex plane by itself, it needs to find a partner so that one moves up and the other down; this probability to find a partner  gives the $\sqrt N$ law.

Comment: With just randomness perhaps the prob of eigenvalues being real is $\frac{\mu(\text{real line segment})}{ \mu(\text{disk})} \approx 0$, where $\mu$ is a measure of Euclidean spaces. //The linked paper says 'The sensitivity of the spectrum to
perturbations of small norm is captured by the notion of pseudo-spectrum.' So we may say thr real eigenvalues here are much less sensitive to perturbations?

Comment: it's a symmetry reason, as I tried to explain in my previous comment; a single real eigenvalue can not move off the real axis without violating the complex conjugation symmetry.